# Attempt by method 'HttpConfiguration..ctor(HttpRouteCollection)' to access method 'HttpConfiguration.DefaultFormatters()' failed

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web API that has version 5.1.2 of the `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client` package installed.

I am trying to access the API from an ASP.NET MVC application, which also has the same version of the package installed.

However, in the Global.asax of the Web API project, on the line below, I get the following exception:

```
WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
```

*Attempt by method 'System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration..ctor(System.Web.Http.HttpRouteCollection)' to access method 'System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration.DefaultFormatters()' failed.*

Comment: According to [this recent SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23433875/access-method-system-web-http-httpconfiguration-defaultformatters-failed), the same error was fixed by updating the libraries from nuget. It might be some (in)compatibility between the MVC and Web API packages. Worth a shot, I guess...

Comment: i am also getting such error have you got solution?

Answer (score 2):

I found that this error occurs when you have multiple projects pointing to different .net versions.

For example if you have a Web API project targeting .net 4.5 and a unit test project targeting .net 4.5.3 it seems that default settings mean nuget may silently update the .net 4.5 project references to incompatible versions one day when you open visual studio and cause your Web API project to fail with the recondite 'Attempt by method 'HttpConfiguration..ctor(HttpRouteCollection)' to access method 'HttpConfiguration.DefaultFormatters()' failed' error.

To avoid the error drop the higher .net version back on the new project to match the Web API project - for this example right click the unit test project, click properties, then change the target framework to .net framework 4.5.

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was a discrepancy between versions of `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client` and `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core`, I tried updating both to the same version and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the issue was solved when I installed the `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core` as well. So three libraries should present and be in harmony (uninstall / install) `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client`, `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core` and `Newtonsoft.json`

Answer (score 0):

same for the above answers in my case also it is working good after updating or reinstalling packages

```
Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client
Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core
```