# What can I uninstall after upgrade to ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, uninstallation

I have upgraded the server to ASP.MVC 5.

In Control Panel in Installed Programes, I found:

```
ASP.NET MVC 2
ASP.NET MVC 3
ASP.NET MVC 4
ASP.NET MVC 4 Runtime
```

It is safe to uninstall all of this older ASP.NET MVC? There is no ASP.NET MVC 5 in list. It is because it was installed via Nuget?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MVC is bin deployable](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/running-an-asp-net-mvc-3-app-on-a-web-server-that-doesn-t-have-asp-net-mvc-3-installed) - meaning that you don't have to install it at all if you don't want to. Earlier versions of MVC were easier to run if you had installed them, so this is probably why you have installations.

By default, anything you fetch from nuget is bin deployed (as it isn't installed on your machine, the files are added to your project).

You can safely remove any installed MVC packages - and if you do have projects that depend upon them, you can install MVC in any project using nuget, and specifying a version (back to version 3) - for example:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc -Version 3.0.50813.1
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc -Version 4.0.40804
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc -Version 5.2.0
```

There are no dependencies of newer MVC versions on older ones, they are simply a newer version of the set of dlls, so there should be no issue removing older versions.

Answer (score 0):

> There are no dependencies of newer MVC versions on older ones, they are simply a newer version of the set of dlls, so there should be no issue removing older versions.

Are you sure???

NuGet decided to upgrade an MVC 4 to 5 box and it hosed the solution.  Right now, I have this problem:

[access method 'System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration.DefaultFormatters()' failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23433875/access-method-system-web-http-httpconfiguration-defaultformatters-failed)

But, any solution found on the web right now has not worked.

It seems Microsoft is back to the ol' marketing tricks, bundling crap galore and creating an *evangelizing* environment where those using their technologies spend an inordinate amount of time on THEIR technologies, not the end solutions. I'm so frickin' mad that if my solution doesn't start working soon I'm tossing Asp.Net MVC after using it for four version with ZERO problems like this and going node.js.